# Scrape Google-Search results page in PHP for total results and parse them

Tags: php, parsing, curl, screen-scraping

good day dear buddies,

well i tried to write a PHP-Parser that runs against google - Well - it takes the value of $query to whatever i want to search for. So far so good. Well this grabs the links of the first 100 results, but as you can see it would be easy to toss in a loop and grab far more 
if needed.  Oh, btw, advices for making the running this parser more sophisticated and better  would be nice, if any. Still, easy-to-learn and easy-to-implement. Just started learning PHP. See the frist snippets...Note - they do  not make use of Curl which is a great great tool Guess that i would improve with Curl.- a lot!

```
<?php
$query = urlencode("my kewords");
preg_match_all('/<a title=".*?" href=(.*?)>/', file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/ie?q=" . urlencode($query) . "&num=100&start=1"), $matches);
print implode("<br>", $matches[1]);
?>
```

What do you say!? This might be called a very very first step.  But i got aware of the **http://google-rank-checker.squabbel.com/**

Well the guys over there implemented a great scraper and paerser. I'd like to use it and learn more PHP in the meanwhile.

I had a quick read up at the google-rank-checker.squabbel.com article, Well this tool contains a full featured scraper in PHP.  One can use that scraper,modify it to the requirements and add the code of phpsimplehtmlparser to get the total-hits information for the keywords. This looks nice too. What do you say!?

love to hear from you 
zero

Oh, btw, advices for running this parser would be nice, if any. 
Still, easy-to-learn and easy-to-implement. Just started learning PHP.

Comment: Ironic usernames always make my day.

Comment: Hello dear HarHaHu - thx for the hints. Tried to figure out where they obtain the keys.. will do it again.. greetings

Comment: after reading it twice i have gained some knowlege - well i guess that for scraping we need a number of high quality IP,
The script is able to correctly manage such IPs (delays, switching between IPs etc). The developer has  used a number of proxy servers in the past and had a lot of issues, 

SEO-Proxies works flawless for him - he said.

Well  do i need several ips or can i run the script without any ip!?

Answer (score 2):

They have an API for custom search

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Comment: hello dear gosu kiwi - thx for answering - well  that means( if i get you right, i do **not** need that script at all!? I will head over to the link you posted and will read all i can read. Many many thanks in advance. Greetings